# SVG looking bad in small resolution?

Tags: images, svg, png, image-quality

I've cretaed a SVG image trying to solve the quality problem when re-sizing the element or scaling it through CSS.

To my surprise, my SVG image looks even worse than the reduced size of the GIF or JPG image.

Here's an image showing what I mean:

[image]

I thought SVG would show a better quality because it resizes without quality lost. 
Why is this happening then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common misconception. Scalable does not mean *infinitely*  scalable. Not all svg renderers and files are created equal

What vector graphics bring to the table is rasterizing on demand. This means that the application showing them can redo the art. This is wonderfull at big sizes but requires special attention when images are small. This is why fonts are "hintted", in essence the font has bitmap versions for small sizes.  Truth is at small scales your image needs to be designed to hit the pixels.

Second theres no particular guarantee that the renderer, that takes the vector data and makes bitmaps, does a good job. Each app does a different result, but here quite clearly the aa engine is antialiasing to black, which is wrong. This is quite typical with engines that do not supersample the graphic.

Comment: But then why is there this tendency of using SVGs for small icons?

Comment: Because you can easily change components of the logo designs for different sizes. For example, for the smallest size, do you really need all lines or the truck and the substructure of the cargo area? Wouldn't a simplified truck model and cargo of the same color, but less subdivisions do just fine? It's not "one design fits all sizes", but rather "one design is easily adaptable to all sizes".

See http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/ for one example of how CSS can be used to make a logo simple if less space is available. (Maybe this should be an answer...)

Comment: Love the concept "rasterizing on demand". (+1)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score -2):

Totally wrong idea, I disagree with you. SVG image better than PNG lot. It never lose quality while you reducing size. And easier way to changing Design control, compress well and support to all devices well.

Comment: "easier way to changing Design control" is the crucial point, the remainder of you answer are not that helpful. For example, a carefully designed PNG icon will look vastly better at a small than an arbitrary SVG icon that has merely been scaled down. SVGs advantage there is that it can be designed carefully as well, has the added charm that it can e.g. be controlled via SVG, and can be the source for those carefully desinged PNG icons - which you might still need just because SVG is not supported by the device you are using.

Comment: Mr.Michael am using SVG image for my client I can do the all type of work (resize, design control and all devices).
If you have more doubt can you please check the link given below
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Have looked at it. I still maintain that you got the most important part of SVG in your answer, but the remainder is less helpful (note that I didn't write "bad" or "wrong"). The question here is effectively "Why does the scaled down SVG file look (subjectively) worse than a scaled down PNG file; somebody told me that SVG files scale perfectly?".

Comment: Did you tried before SVG image is not perfectly scale?

Comment: I have told you already "am using SVG image for my client I can do the all type of work (resize, design control and all devices)"

Comment: Yes, you told me that. But have a look at the example image of the initial question. Compare the substructure of the truck's cargo area, for example - the scale down PNG version looks much closer to the larger-scale PNG file than the scaled-down SVG version. The SVG and PNG images are not identical to begin with - but one would really not expect that result for SVG.

Comment: @Senthilkumar: I don't think general statements such as "SVG image better than PNG" can ever be true. I agree that SVG is "more flexible" than PNG because they can be re-sized and tampered with easily from code. But the SVG format cannot be used in some applications, like Michael mentioned. For example, Gmail HTML emails do not support SVG. Period. They do not render them. Each format has its own use. Lets not be "formatist" (my failed attempt to be funny and mix "racists" with "format").